# Trouble getting parameter sets to validate

Tags: powershell

I have a function that I have been working on a while, but have shelved for a couple of months due to some frustrations with getting the parameter sets to work properly. It is meant to be part of an internal tool kit for transferring AD accounts between sites. There are several parameter sets that will be needed:

```
Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-RetainGroups] [-TransferMDrive] [-OldServer <String>] [-NewServer <String>]
[<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-RetainGroups] [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-RemoveFromAllGroups] [-TransferMDrive] [-OldServer <String>] [-NewServer
<String>] [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-RemoveFromAllGroups] [<CommonParameters>]

Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-TransferMDrive] -OldServer <String> -NewServer <String> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Basically, `RetainGroups` and `RemoveFromAllGroups` must be mutually exclusive. `TransferMDrive` could be included with either of those, or run on it's own.

Right now, I can only run `RetainGroups` and `RemoveFromAllGroups` if I include the `TransferHomeDrive` parameter. If I try any of those 3 on their own, I get the following:

```
Move-AccountOut : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-AccountOut -Username testuser -RetainGroups
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-AccountOut], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Move-AccountOut
```

I have posted questions about issues with this function before, but I still cannot get it to resolve the parameter sets correctly. According to the `get-help` output above, it should work, as far as I can tell.

Here is what my `param` looks like:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='OnlyUser')]
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainOnly')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer')]
    [switch]$RetainGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveOnly')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer')]
    [switch]$RemoveFromAllGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer')]
    [switch]$TransferMDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer')]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer')]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is how your parametersets expand out (see below).  Basically given just those two parameters (Username and RetainGroups) - there are two valid parametetsets (RetainOnly and RetainAndTransfer) neither of which is the `default` parameter set.  I think you need to make TransferMDrive mandatory for the two Transfer parametersets e.g.:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer', Mandatory = $True)]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveAndTransfer', Mandatory = $True)]
[switch]$TransferMDrive,
```

Expanded out (original) parametersets:

```
    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    OnlyUser *


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All     


    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    RetainAndTransfer


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
NewServer              {N*}         Named    False     False    False  All     
OldServer              {Ol*}        Named    False     False    False  All     
RetainGroups           {Ret*}       Named    False     False    False  All     
TransferMDrive         {T*}         Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All     


    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    RetainOnly


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
RetainGroups           {Ret*}       Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All     


    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    RemoveAndTransfer


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
NewServer              {N*}         Named    False     False    False  All     
OldServer              {Ol*}        Named    False     False    False  All     
RemoveFromAllGroups    {Rem*}       Named    False     False    False  All     
TransferMDrive         {T*}         Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All     


    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    RemoveOnly


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
RemoveFromAllGroups    {Rem*}       Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All     


    Command: Function:/Move-AccountOut
    Set:    TransferMDrive


Name                   Aliases      Position Mandatory Pipeline ByName Provider
----                   -------      -------- --------- -------- ------ --------
InformationAction      {infa}       Named    False     False    False  All     
InformationVariable    {iv}         Named    False     False    False  All     
NewServer              {N*}         Named    True      False    False  All     
OldServer              {Ol*}        Named    True      False    False  All     
TransferMDrive         {T*}         Named    False     False    False  All     
Username               {U*}         Named    True      True     True   All
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm further than I've been in months. 5 of my 6 parameter sets are working now, the only one that isn't is `Move-AccountOut -Username <String> [-TransferMDrive] -OldServer <String> -NewServer <String> [<CommonParameters>]`. Tried making `TransferMDrive` mandatory, but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to your parameterset design, if you specify -TransferMDrive as well as -Old/NewServer, PowerShell can narrow it down to the TransferMDrive parameterset.  However, if -TransferMDrive isn't specified, given params -Username, -OldServer and -NewServer, PowerShell can't disambiguate between the RetainAndTransfer and RemoveAndTransfer parametersets.  I think you need `[Parameter(ParameterSetName='RetainAndTransfer', Mandatory=$True)]
    [switch]$RetainGroups`.  Ditto for the RemoveGroups parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may be over complicating it a bit. You are using switches for retaining or removing the groups. Can you just combine them into one switch? If so, you can cut out all the other parameter sets.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$Username,

    [switch]$RetainGroups,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive')]
    [switch]$TransferMDrive,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$OldServer,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='TransferMDrive', Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$NewServer
)
```

So by default it will not retain the groups and you can set the flag to keep them. Or if it needs to be the other way, flip it around.

Comment: I totally agree. That was my original design. I changed it however because  there is code further down in my script that will confirm removal for each individual group if no parameter is specified. Using one of the retain/remove switches would bypass that and automatically take the correct action. **HOWEVER**, now that I am thinking about it, would adding another switch to trigger the confirmation be better practice? Like, I could flip your example and add a `-PromptForConfirmation` switch instead.